# How to enlarge latex fragments in org mode at the same time as the buffer text?

Tags: image, emacs, latex, zooming

I'm using `org-mode` in emacs, but I think the question is also relevant for `auctex` users.

In `org-mode` you can show latex fragments, as the [manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Previewing-LaTeX-fragments.html) demonstrates.

But: these fragments (mostly math formulae) seem to have *constant* size.  When I type `C-x C-+` or `C-x C--` *only* the buffer text size changes.  How can I change the fragments size from the buffer?

(I know I can make the fragments larger or smaller with `org-format-latex-options`, but this is permanent. I want to change the size of the fragments (the png files) like the text.)